# iTextSharp xmlworker - how to set dotted table border from html

Tags: c#, html, css, itext, xmlworker

Hello all you smart people of StackOverflow.

I was given a task yesterday to convert [this](http://www.hzzo.hr/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Uputnica.pdf?831c2f) scanned image to PDF document.
As I don't have time to learn all tips and tricks of iText, I decided to use xmlWorker and create an HTML template of the document itself.
I was quite successful, the ending result is this:

[image: Converted PDF file]

HOWEVER!

Not everything went smoothly. If you take a closer look at the scanned document, you may notice that in the middle of the document there is a table with dashed border. And this is where my headache starts.
I've been googling for the past 15 hrs trying to find a solution for this, but was not successful. I've tried all kinds of CSS border definitions like:

- border-left-style: dashed;
- border-style: dashed;
- border: dashed;

It seems that these CSS definitions are simply ignored.

So my question is this, is there a proper way to define an HTML table with dashed border so it can be properly converted to PDF document?

I am using latest iTextSharp from Nuget (v. 5.5.12).

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**

Ok, so 24 hrs later I think I have an answer.
It is a combination of these two examples:

http://codejaxy.com/q/395523/c-23-html-asp-net-itextsharp-xmlworker-using-itextsharp-xmlworker-to-convert-html-to-pdf-and-write-text-vertically

[One cell with different border types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555756/one-cell-with-different-border-types)

Basically I implemented IPdfPCellEvent interface so I could use a CellEvent on a PdfCell:

```
public class DottedCell : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    private readonly int _border = 0;

    public DottedCell(int border)
    {
        _border = border;
    }

    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
    {
        var canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        canvas.SaveState();
        canvas.SetLineDash(0, 2, 2);

        cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

        if ((_border & Rectangle.TOP_BORDER) == Rectangle.TOP_BORDER)
        {
            canvas.MoveTo(position.GetRight(1), position.GetTop(1));
            canvas.LineTo(position.GetLeft(1), position.GetTop(1));
        }
        if ((_border & Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER) == Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER)
        {
            canvas.MoveTo(position.GetRight(1), position.GetBottom(1));
            canvas.LineTo(position.GetLeft(1), position.GetBottom(1));
        }
        if ((_border & Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER) == Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER)
        {
            canvas.MoveTo(position.GetRight(1), position.GetTop(1));
            canvas.LineTo(position.GetRight(1), position.GetBottom(1));
        }
        if ((_border & Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER) == Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER)
        {
            canvas.MoveTo(position.GetLeft(1), position.GetTop(1));
            canvas.LineTo(position.GetLeft(1), position.GetBottom(1));
        }
        canvas.Stroke();
        canvas.RestoreState();
    }
}
```

After that I overrode a iTextSharp.tool.xml.html.table.TableData class:

```
public class TableDataProcessor : TableData
{
    bool HasBorderStyle(IDictionary<string, string> attributeMap, string borderPosition, string borderStyle)
    {
        var hasStyle = attributeMap.ContainsKey("style");

        if (!hasStyle)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var borderLeft = attributeMap["style"]
            .Split(';')
            .FirstOrDefault(o => o.Trim().StartsWith("border-style-" + borderPosition + ":"));

        if (borderLeft != null)
        {
            return borderLeft.Split(':').Any(o => o.Trim().ToLower() == borderStyle);
        }

        return false;
    }



    public override IList<IElement> End(IWorkerContext ctx, Tag tag, IList<IElement> currentContent)
    {
        var cells = base.End(ctx, tag, currentContent);

        var attributeMap = tag.Attributes;
        if (HasBorderStyle(attributeMap, "left", "dotted"))
        {
            var pdfPCell = (PdfPCell) cells[0];
            pdfPCell.CellEvent = null;
            pdfPCell.CellEvent = new DottedCell(Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER);
        }

        return cells;
    }
}
```

The last step was to add that class to tag processor for a TD element:

```
var tagProcessorFactory = Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
tagProcessorFactory.AddProcessor(
     new TableDataProcessor(),
     new[] {HTML.Tag.TD}
);

htmlContext.SetTagFactory(tagProcessorFactory);
```

And it works:
[image]

HTML markup:

```
<table class="content-wrapper">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="pcnt_60 content-left top" valign="top">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td style='border-left: 0.5px; border-style-left: dotted;'>content goes here</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```